# Power BI get average time

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, desktop

i want to get the average time when a truck is arriving here.

I need to get the datetime value of the column "date" from the last record that has a "Gestellnummer" of 18 and the first record that has the "Gestellnummer" of 1.

- So in this example, the last record of "Gestellnummer" 18 is: 27.05.2020 15:13:37
- And the first record of "Gestellnummer" 1 is: 27.05.2020 16:39:15

Now i need to subtract the last record from the first record, to get the time value that i need.

I need to do this in Power BI for each time "Gestellnummer" is 18 or 1, as explained above. In this table, i have over 10000 records, and i need to get the average time of all those time values.

I tried to make a query which only shows all records that have "Gestellnummer" of 18 or 1. But i still do not know how i can subtract one datetime value from the other in the same column...

I hope somebody can help me out with this one..

Thank you in advance and have a great day

[image]

Comment: You need to get the times on the same row. Is there any common key that groups these together? Or is this purely based on one happening after the other one?

Comment: it is purely based on one happening after the other. Every time a truck is arriving here and it starts unloading goods, a new line is created inside this table with the information in the picture. How can i get the times on the same row? In Excel this would be easy, but i can't think of a way inside power bi..

Comment: This is the general concept that you are trying to solve. It's not trivial. Personally I would do this in the database beforehand. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Calculating-time-between-check-in-and-check-out-from-different/td-p/326150